# How to add two different documents from firestore on a listView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

```
    2018-12-30 02:10:29.444 25245-25245/com.example.gusta.realapp D/rest1: firestorebookn1
re#564738
    2018-12-30 02:10:29.446 25245-25245/com.example.gusta.realapp D/rest1: firestorebookn2
```

I am getting two different documents from a collection on firestore,and I am trying to add them into a list view, but its not working because it always get the last one received, an example is the Log above, in my list view it would appear the firestorebookn2 two times, and not one time firestorebookn1 and firestorebookn2.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("books").document(parametro);
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    String book = "book1";
                    String BOOK = "bookname";

                Integer x = 0;
                while(x<10) {
                    x++;

                     BOOK = document.getString(book);

                    if (BOOK.equals("0") ) {
                        break;
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG,BOOK);
                        Log.d(TAG,book);

                        ListView book1 = findViewById(R.id.bookview);
                        ArrayAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mbook(BOOK));
                        book1.setAdapter(adapter);


                        BOOK = BOOK+1;
                       book = book+1;

                    }


                }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I added some more info regarding my problem.

Comment: The code you shared creates a new adapter for each book: `ArrayAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mbook(BOOK));`. If you want to show multiple books, you'll need to create a single adapter with all books in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you shared creates a new adapter for each book:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mbook(BOOK));
```

If you want to show multiple books, you'll need to create a single adapter with all books in it.